# Where condition in count function in LINQ

Tags: linq

I have a LINQ statement like below:

```cs
var pairs = new [] { 
    new { id = 1, name = "ram", dept = "IT", sal = "3000" }, 
    new { id = 2, name = "ramesh", dept = "IT", sal = "5000" }, 
    new { id = 3, name = "rahesh", dept = "NONIT", sal = "2000" },
    new { id = 5, name = "rash", dept = "NONIT", sal = "7000" }
};
var query = (from dynamic stud in pairs
             group stud by stud.dept into grps
             select new { 
                 IT = grps.Count(stud => stud.dept == "IT"), 
                 NONIT = grps.Count(stud => stud.dept == "NONIT") 
             });
```

Here I am getting the `IT` and `NONIT` count, but I am getting two rows of results and each group is querying separately. Can I count both of them at a single go? The output I am getting here if I for-loop the query like below is 2,0 and 0,2

```
foreach (dynamic result in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.IT + "," + result.NONIT);
}
```

This is because each group is querying separately. I am looking for a result like 2,2.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you know exactly that department names is either "IT" or "NONIT",  and the result should be single data, you can get the expected output without grouping :

```
var result2 = new
              {
                  IT = (from dynamic stud in pairs where stud.dept == "IT" select stud).Count(),
                  NONIT = (from dynamic stud in pairs where stud.dept == "NONIT" select stud).Count()
              };
Console.WriteLine(result.IT + "," + result.NONIT);
```

or if you favor grouping, I suggest to convert query result to dictionary to easily lookup count by department name :

```
var query = (from dynamic stud in pairs
              group stud by stud.dept
              into grps
              select
                  new
                  {
                      Dept = grps.Key,
                      Count = grps.Count()
                  }).ToDictionary(o => o.Dept, o => o.Count);

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("result : {0}", query["IT"] + "," + query["NONIT"]));
```

If none of above suits your requirement, please update the question to explain more about what you're trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: it worked like a charm, both of the solutions are awesome,Thanks